# Determining if a string is a palindrome of a permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, palindrome

I wrote code to determine if a string is a palindrome of a permutation. This exercise was taken from *Cracking the Coding Interview*. I'm looking for any tips on improving it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/*
*   Determine if a string is a palindrome of a permutation.
*   For simplicity, assume each string contains ONLY alphabetical characters.
*/

//strip string of non-alphabetical characters
std::string strip_junk(std::string s){
    std::string output("");
    for(char& c : s)
        if(isalpha(c)){
            c = tolower(c);
            output += c;
        }
    return output;
}

//determine how many times each character appears in the string
int *get_char_counts(std::string input){
    static const int ascii_sub = 97;
    static int counters[26]{0};
    for(char c : input){
        counters[c - ascii_sub]++; //if c='a', c-ascii_sub = 0. if c='z', c-ascii_sub = 25
    }
    return counters;
}

//check if more than one character appears an odd number of times
bool check_chars(std::string input){
    int *char_counter = get_char_counts(input);
    bool flag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i){
        if(*(char_counter + i) % 2 != 0){ //if number is odd, check if it appeared twice
            if(flag)
                return false; //it appeared twice, return false
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//check if string is a palindrome of a permutation
bool palindromePermutation(std::string input){
    input = strip_junk(input);
    return check_chars(input);
}

int main(void){
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << (palindromePermutation(input) ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This: `tolower(c);` looks broken. You probably intended it to be `c=tolower(c);` instead. `tolower` doesn't modify its argument--it just returns the lower-case equivalent.

Comment: @JerryCoffin you're absolutely right. That is such a stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: I dont understand what does palindrome of permutation means. All permutations are palindrom of a set of numbers themself's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd change a number of things in this code.

> ```
> std::string output("");
> ```

No need for the empty initializer--it'll be initialized to an empty string by default (i.e., `std::string output;` is fine).

> ```
> for(char& c : s)
>     if(isalpha(c)){
>         c = tolower(c);
>         output += c;
>     }
> ```

I don't see where you gain anything by modifying the input string here, instead of just writing the modified character to the output:

```
for (char c : s)
    if (isalpha(c))
        output += tolower(c);
```

Unfortunately, things aren't quite that simple. In most implementations, a plain char is signed, and passing a negative number to `isalpha` or `tolower` gives undefined behavior. Anytime you call either, you really need to convert to `unsigned char` first:

```
for (unsigned char c : s) 
    if (isalpha(c))
       output += tolower(c);
```

Now when somebody tests with (for example) an accented character, it won't crash and burn.

> ```
> static const int ascii_sub = 97;
> ```

This strikes me as wrong in at least a couple of different ways. First, the name strikes me as poor (ASCII, as such, is mostly obsolete, and even before that, it was unnecessarily narrow). I guess you mean the `sub` to refer to subtraction (somehow or other) but it's not immediately apparent how the two combine meaningfully.

Worse, it appears that your real intent is to just get the value of `a`. If you want that, it's almost always better to just use `'a'`.

> ```
> static int counters[26]{0};
> ```

Here I'd rather use something like `static size_t counters['z'-'a'];` Since it's static, it'll be initialized to zeros automatically. Using `'z' - 'a'` makes it apparent what that `26` is intended to signify--and as a bonus, even makes it work with systems that use EBCDIC, where the distance from `a` to `z` is more than 26.

And, of course, the standard type for counting things where you can't ever have negative values is `size_t` (though a signed int like you've used will typically be perfectly fine).

Rather than using a static array, I'd probably use a `std::vector` (not `static`, and return it by value rather than returning a pointer to it).

Looking at `check_chars`, I think I'd do things a bit differently.  I'd probably use `std::find_if` to do the searching, something like this:

```
auto first = find_if(counts.begin(), counts.end(), [](size_t s) { return s % 2 != 0); });

auto second = find_if(first, counts.end(), [](size_t s) { return s % 2 != 0; });

return second != counts.end();
```

The first tries to find an odd value. The second tries to find a second odd value between the first, and the end. If the first failed, it'll return `counts.end()`. The second will try to search between the end and the end, and obviously conclude no such thing exists (very quickly), so it'll return `counts.end()` as well.

Finally this:

> ```
> std::cout << (palindromePermutation(input) ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
> ```

...can be simplified a bit as well:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << palindromePermutation(input) << "\n";
```

`std::boolalpha` is not only a bit shorter, but also uses the names defined in the locale, so when using (for example) a German locale, it could print out `falsch` and `wahr` (and with a Chinese locale, if Google Translate is to be trusted, `假` and `真`) for "false" and "true", respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Lots of great stuff. I especially like your suggestion to use `c-'a'` and `static size_t counters['z'-'a']`. I will also have to greatly familiarize myself with the C++ `<algorithm>` header functions.